# connect vertex ai endpoint through .Net

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nlp, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Is there any way to connected google cloud platform service vertex ai endpoint through .Net code ? I am new to gcp vertex. any help is really apricated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could refer to [Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1 documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1/latest) for reference for dot net. You can start by:

1. Installing the package from [Google AI Platform nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1/)
2. If you don't have an endpoint yet you can check out [Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1.EndpointServiceClient](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1.EndpointServiceClient). You can use this class to manage endpoints like create endpoint, delete endpoint, deploy endpoint, etc.

   - Check this [EndpointServiceClient code sample](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/main/apis/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1.Snippets/IndexEndpointServiceClientSnippets.g.cs) for usage.
3. If you have an endpoint and you want to run predictions using it, you can check out [Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1.PredictionServiceClient](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1.PredictionServiceClient). You can use this class to perform prediction using your endpoint.

   - Specifically [Predict(EndpointName, IEnumerable, Value, CallSettings)](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1.PredictionServiceClient#Google_Cloud_AIPlatform_V1_PredictionServiceClient_Predict_Google_Cloud_AIPlatform_V1_EndpointName_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_Google_Protobuf_WellKnownTypes_Value__Google_Protobuf_WellKnownTypes_Value_Google_Api_Gax_Grpc_CallSettings_) method where it accepts an endpoint as parameter.
   - Check this [PredictionServiceClient code sample](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/main/apis/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1.Snippets/PredictionServiceClientSnippets.g.cs) for usage.

Comment: I got to item 3 but get exception "Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Unimplemented", Detail="Bad gRPC response. HTTP status code: 404")'". Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Importantly! for Vertex AI you must specify a region endpoint when calling your custom trained model. See Java sample link.

```
const string regionEndpoint = "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com:443";
try
{
    // Create client
    var serviceClientBuilder = new PredictionServiceClientBuilder
    {
        Endpoint = regionEndpoint
    };
    var predictionServiceClient = await serviceClientBuilder.BuildAsync();
    ...

}
```

[Java sample with custom endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/get-online-predictions#online_predict_custom_trained-java)